# How to prove that series $\sum (-1)^n\sin^4n /\sqrt{n}$ converges?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have a series:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{\sin^4n}{\sqrt n}.$$
How can we prove that it converges?

---

Usually, with $\sin^4n$ we would use Comparison Test, but it only applies when the terms are nonnegative.

Comment: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/AlternatingSeries.aspx

Comment: @bburGsamohT Is that function strictly decreasing?  You need that for the AST.

Comment: @GregoryGrant Compare it with the series $\sum(-1)^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$

Comment: @bburGsamohT If you use the limit comparison test with that series, I don't think the ratio $\sin^4 n$ converges.  So I still think there's a gap in the argument.

Comment: If $\alpha$ is not a multiple of $2\pi$, then the partial sums $\sum_{n = 1}^N e^{i\alpha n}$ are bounded. $(-1)^n\sin^4 n = \frac{e^{i\pi n}}{16}(e^{in} - e^{-in})^4$. Ask Dirichlet.

Comment: @bburGsamohT we can compare series that have only non-negative terms.

Comment: @stacy right, my fault on that. I always seem to oversimplify these problems.

Comment: Note that $$\sum\frac{(-1)^n\sin^4(n\pi/2)}{\sqrt{n}}$$ diverges, so make sure your proof does not apply in that case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Noting that
$$ \sin^4n=\frac{1}{8}(3-4\cos(2n)+\cos(4n)) $$ 
you have
\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{\sin^4n}{\sqrt n}&=&\frac{3}{8}\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{1}{\sqrt n}-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{\cos(2n)}{\sqrt n}+\frac{1}{8}\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{\cos(4n)}{\sqrt n}.
\end{eqnarray}
Now you can do the rest to show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{\cos(2n)}{\sqrt n}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{\cos(4n)}{\sqrt n}$ are convergent.